# Why does Stack Overflow use Flash?

Tags: support, status-completed, advertising

EDIT 2/25/2015:

This seems to have regressed. I was asked to run Flash a few minutes ago. Here is the markup.

[image]

For this ad:

[image]

Original post:

This morning I opened Stack Overflow, and for this first time ever, I was asked if I wanted to run Flash.

[image: Flash Prompt]

This happened while on the "Interesting" tab.

Why did Stack Overflow start using Flash? Is it essential that I allow it, or can I safely say "Never"?

EDIT:

It appears to be ad related. I managed to reproduce it and caught the offender:

[image]

EDIT2:

It's coming from an ad.doubleclick.net `iframe`.

Comment: Ads, probably? Where do you see that, the front page or a specific page? Do you use an ad blocker?

Comment: @l4mpi I updated my question. I agree on the ads, but I am not seeing `object` tags anywhere, so it is a little tricky to figure out where it is being used. Perhaps some clipboard copying functionality was introduced that I haven't come across yet.

Comment: I severely doubt it as I didn't see anything yet - while it's possible that SE is A/B testing a new feature and I'm in the wrong group, the possibility that it's an ad is way higher.

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, or perhaps your browser is just loading it without asking.

Comment: No, it would complain about a missing plugin, which I'd see - I don't have flash installed on this machine.

Comment: Malware. Something you installed is injecting stuff into the web page. I'm 100% sure Stack Overflow does not send any flash contents to the browser.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, but I think you are jumping to conclusions. It could be an occasionally served ad, which is why I ask.

Comment: @vcsjones very low chance, since Stack Overflow clearly disallow animation or flash in their advertisements.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 3rd party ad services make mistakes, perhaps AdZerk accidentally let one through.

Comment: Well, Tim is looking into it now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I reproduced it - it's an ad of some kind. I get it 1/30 page loads when I am not signed in (otherwise I get reduced ads)

Comment: Actually that beacon is legit and used to track usage of Stack Overflow. I [detected it long ago too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210658/houston-we-are-web-bugged).

Comment: @vcsjones There's nothing we know of that should be doing this. Can you tell us which ad?

Comment: @DavidFullerton I don't think it is an ad, it's some kind of analytics, or I have malware (unlikely, but don't want to throw away any possibility yet).

Comment: @vcsjones I've got a repro so it's not malware on your end

Comment: @DavidFullerton *phew*.

Comment: *It's coming from an ad.doubleclick.net* yet another reason for installing Adblock.

Comment: I have AdBlock, but I have deliberately disabled it for Stack Overflow. I think the website more than deserves whatever ad revenue it can get.

Comment: I would also disable my Adblock if there was a way to do so without compromising my privacy... sadly there is no such way.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Thank you for spotting this and bringing it to our attention.

This is not a tracking beacon used by us-- this is within an ad itself. As you know, we take your privacy *very* seriously, and ask the same of our advertisers. The campaign is now paused and we are communicating with the advertiser in question.

As far as we can tell this is isolated to that one campaign, so if you see this again please let us know.

---

Update: the advertiser in question removed the content and the campaign is now running again.

Thank you again for spotting this. We do what we can to ensure that nothing is in a creative tag that shouldn't be there before going live, but sometimes things slip through. This is one of those instances. I truly appreciate the extra eyeballs on the lookout for things like this.

Comment: Although the SWF format is already dying, as a Flash animator you have no idea how happy I am to hear that folks like SE go out of their way to avoid the use of Flash in ads - they gave Flash a bad rep that it absolutely didn't deserve.

Comment: Wow so many wrong assumptions on my side... glad it's all sorted out now! :)

Comment: @BoltClock - As somebody who cares about computer security, I'm glad they avoid allowing Flash for completely different reasons.

Comment: @Mr. Llama: I think those reasons contribute to the bad rep all the same.

Comment: @stevvve this is still an issue. I just got a Flash run prompt for a flash object in an ad for Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: @vcsjones They've disabled the questionable items that appeared to be beacons. The remaining flash object is part of a product the client is using called AdSafe (now IntegralAds). They use it, as I understand it, to prevent ad fraud. http://integralads.com/data-metrics/ad-fraud/

That said: conversations are on-going. Any relevant updates will be here.