# What should I do when I notice a Flash tracker in an ad?

Tags: support, advertising

Related to "[Why does Stack Overflow use Flash?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286172/why-does-stack-overflow-use-flash)."

I noticed Firefox asking me to allow Flash on SO this morning. Based on the reaction to the post I linked below, I am assuming this should not be allowed.

Upon further inspection, I saw:

[image: source of flash on home page]

which came from this Microsoft Azure ad iframe:

```
<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow adzerk-vote" id="adzerk1396402438">
<iframe scrolling="no" id="ados_frame_adzerk1396402438_633238"
   frameborder="0" height="250" width="220"></iframe> ...
```

Is reporting use of Flash in ads on Meta still appropriate and/or recommended?

Comment: Yes it is, but I would rather close this as a dupe of the question you found.

Comment: I left a comment on the answer on the dupe, that should ping the correct SE employees...